# Keycloak custom theme messages encoding and russian localization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

Problem: Keycloak can't use russian symbols in the message_ru.properties file.
Question: How to use russian custom messages in the keycloak?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy a template message_ru.properties file to your directory
2. Set the "# encoding: utf-8" string to the first row
3. Go to the ISO-8859-1 encoding files to UTF-8 converter (https://utf8-iso-convert.netlify.app);
4. Write your message in russian and convert your UTF-8 russian sentence to the ISO format.
5. Copy your ISO format sentence to your file like:
   [image]
6. Upload to your Git!

**Important!** The problem is that it's working differently on the production mode and the development, so just check this solution **only in PRODUCTION**